# Using <space> as prefix key in normal mode, cursor will advance one character itself

Tags: key-bindings, normal-mode

I put key mapping like this `nnoremap <space>d "_d` in my `.vimrc`, so I can delete text more comfortable. But when I in visual mode or visual block mode, the cursor will advance one more column, and delete more than I wanted.
 I know I can change `<space>` to other key, like `<alt>`, and it works fine. But `<space>` is the most easily to pressed, I still want to use it. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the same mapping in Visual mode as well:

```
nnoremap <space>d "_d
xnoremap <space>d "_d
```

You can also use a simple `noremap`, which maps in Normal, Visual and Selection mode, just in that case you might want to undo the mapping in Selection mode (which is probably inappropriate for that mode):

```
noremap <space>d "_d
sunmap <space>d
```

Comment: There is also `xnoremap` which will map for visual-mode only (no select)

Comment: And if you really like mapping prefixes, consider using mapleader and <leader>

Comment: Thanks for advises.

Comment: @PeterRincker Ah yes, `xnoremap` is what I had in mind! Updated the answer. Thanks!